# PHP form, when category is selected also add category+.png in another row

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I hope my question is clear but Ill try to explain it a bit more.

In my database I have two columns named "category" and "images". In my form people need to add a category so my PHP adds a new entry to MySQL.

What I want is when people choose the correct category, for example "Bingo", I also want to add Bingo to the "image" column but with the expansion of ".png". So when people choose a category there also will be added a image.

This is the part of the form where people need to select their category:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="formlabel">Categorie:</div>
    <div class="formveldcel">
        <select name="categorie">
            <option selected>Selecteer</option>
            <option value="Bingo">Bingo</option>
            <option value="Kaarten">Kaarten</option>
            <option value="Live muziek">Live muziek</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code below adds a title, description, and category to my MySQL database, so that part is working.

```
<?php
    include "db_connection.php";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if(isset($_POST["titel"])){
        $query = $db->prepare("insert into zoekopdrachten (titel, omschrijving, categorie) values (?,?,?)");
        $params=array($_POST["titel"],$_POST["omschrijving"],$_POST["categorie"]);



        if ($query->execute($params)) {
            echo "<div class=\"feedbackgoed\">item toegevoegd. Klik <a href='http://www.bartnooijens.nl/school/webapp-eindopdracht/'>hier</a> om terug te gaan naar de website</div>\n";
        }

    }
?>
```

I'm kind of new to PHP so I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: is that all your codes? where is the image column and so far, what have you explore?

Comment: the image column is in mysql, you think i should add it to the post to clearify?

Comment: so when somebody select a so called correct category, an image will appear beside the dropdown list?

Comment: no, i think i'm not clear enough. When people select a category from the dropdown in the form it will be stored in the category column in mysql. The  "problem" is that i also want the image column to be filled with the category and i want to add ".png" to that.

Check out this webpage to make it even more clear for you: http://www.bartnooijens.nl/school/webapp-eindopdracht/index.php

Comment: are you saying, if I choose bingo, you want to add a string bingo.png(letters only, not a picture) into column image?

Comment: So you want to do `$_POST["categorie"].".png"`?

Comment: yes, but i want it to be added in column category aswell. So i need to store it in two columns (in category and in the image column with the expansion of .png)

Comment: so for example:

I choose bingo as category it needs to be stored in category but also in image with .png  added :)

Comment: Is your image column in the `zoekopdrachten` table? What is it called?

Comment: yes it is sean, all my columns are in the zoekopdrachten table. Check out this screenshot to see my database columns: https://gyazo.com/c2c4366bbe1493ff23ce635626b1fc6b

Comment: so what is the image column named?

Comment: it is called "plaatje"

Comment: $_POST['SomeImageNameWithoutExtension'].".png"      will return you "SomeImageNameWithoutExtension.png" you can work on your query from this.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mark, this is about the same as Sean told me and it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the `.png` to the category value when doing your insert by adding it in your `$params` as `$_POST["categorie"].".png"`

```
$query = $db->prepare("insert into zoekopdrachten (titel, omschrijving, categorie, plaatje) values (?,?,?, ?)");
$params=array($_POST["titel"],$_POST["omschrijving"],$_POST["categorie"], $_POST["categorie"].".png");
```

Comment: I see what you do there but users only selected the category and it will be stored in "categorie" in my database. But how do i get my PHP to say, also put the category in the column "plaatje".

Comment: well you add `plaatje` to your column list -> `(titel, omschrijving, categorie, plaatje)`, you add another placeholder in the values ->  `values (?,?,?,?)`, and then you add `$_POST["categorie"].".png"` in your `$params` array -> `array($_POST["titel"],$_POST["omschrijving"],$_POST["categorie"], $_POST["categorie"].".png")`

Comment: Yeah, i see! I thought $_POST["categorie"].".png" would also post it in the category column but that's not what's happening because it looks to what i wrote in insert.